# Change a URI in the style field of an HTML file

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have an HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style type="text/css">

  td[id="module1header"] {
        width: 310px !important;
        height: 75px !important;
        margin-top: 25px;
        text-align: center !important;
        font-size: 21px !important;
        vertical-align: bottom !important;
    }
    td[class="module1"] {
        text-align:center;
        padding:0 0 0 20px !important;
        width:335px;
    }
    span[id="modulediv1"] {
        width: 370px !important;
        height: 379px !important;
        background-image: url(http://www.url.com/somefile.jpg) !important;
    }
</style>
<html>
<head>
```

Using Nokogiri I want to access each URI inside `<style type="text/css"> </style>` and change it.
I was trying something like this:

```
htext= File.open(inputOpts.html_file).read
h_docc = Nokogiri::HTML(htext)
h_doc.css('td[style]').each do |style|
//modify uri hear.
end
```

But that code is not able to access the style. How do I access each URI within the style field and then change it?

Answer (score 1):

`h_doc.css('td[style]')` is a CSS matching method, which in this case matches a `td` with a `style` HTML attribute:

```
>> Nokogiri::HTML('<style></style><td style></td>').css('td[style]').to_s
#=> "<td style></td>"
```

In order to match the `style` tag you have to use the `style` tag selector:

```
>> Nokogiri::HTML('<style></style><td style></td>').css('style').to_s
#=> "<style></style>\n"
```

Comment: thanks for that.. can you also let me know each of inside field such as span[id="modulediv1"] so that I can change the uri.

Comment: Nokogiri doesn't support CSS edits, you have to either use regexps or a Ruby CSS parser (like f.e. [this](https://github.com/premailer/css_parser))

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use Nokogiri, which parses HTML, to parse CSS. You can't get there from here.

Instead, you can use Nokogiri to find the appropriate CSS block, then manipulate it using regular String munging tools:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style type="text/css">

  td[id="module1header"] {
        width: 310px !important;
        height: 75px !important;
        margin-top: 25px;
        text-align: center !important;
        font-size: 21px !important;
        vertical-align: bottom !important;
    }
    td[class="module1"] {
        text-align:center;
        padding:0 0 0 20px !important;
        width:335px;
    }
    span[id="modulediv1"] {
        width: 370px !important;
        height: 379px !important;
        background-image: url(http://www.url.com/somefile.jpg) !important;
    }
</style>
<html>
<head>
EOT
```

At this point `doc` is a DOM which is parsed and ready to be manipulated:

```
new_url = 'http://www.example.com/index.html'

doc.search('style').each do |style|
  style.content = style.content.sub(/\burl\([^)]+\)/, "url(#{ new_url })")
end

puts doc.to_html
```

Running that results in this output:

```
# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# >> <html>
# >> <head>
# >> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
# >> <style type="text/css">
# >> 
# >>   td[id="module1header"] {
# >>         width: 310px !important;
# >>         height: 75px !important;
# >>         margin-top: 25px;
# >>         text-align: center !important;
# >>         font-size: 21px !important;
# >>         vertical-align: bottom !important;
# >>     }
# >>     td[class="module1"] {
# >>         text-align:center;
# >>         padding:0 0 0 20px !important;
# >>         width:335px;
# >>     }
# >>     span[id="modulediv1"] {
# >>         width: 370px !important;
# >>         height: 379px !important;
# >>         background-image: url(http://www.example.com/index.html) !important;
# >>     }
# >> </style>
# >> 
# >> 
# >> </head>
# >> </html>
```

Notice that the embedded URL is now updated.

`doc.search('style')` returns all `<style>` tags found in the document. If you want a specific one you'll need to modify the `'style'` to a more appropriate CSS or XPath selector, or figure out a way to determine whether to continue with that particular tag.

`style.content` returns the content of a tag. That isn't necessarily the text of the tag; CSS style-sheets inside a `<style>` tag are text by definition. `style.content =` is how we assign content to a particular tag, so that code takes the existing CSS style information, performs a `sub` on it, and reassigns it to the tag as the tag's content.

`/\burl\([^)]+\)/` is a regular expression that looks for `url` standing by itself; `\b` is a word boundary. `\([^)]+\)` means "find an opening parenthesis, all text inside it until the next closing parenthesis, and that closing parenthesis." That helps us isolate the chunk of text to be replaced. The rest should be easy to figure out.